# SQL query to handle complex relationship

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have a scenario where I have a large number of blogs.  These blogs all have multiple posts.  Each blog post can link to a post on another blog, but they should then *never* link back from that blog to the linking blog.

To clarify:

- Site A links to Site B (and can link to other Sites)
- Site B then *cannot* link to Site A (but can link to other Sites)

Every time a post is made I store the post's ID and the ID of the website it links to.  It's important to remember that once a single post links to any post on another website that other website cannot link back from **anywhere**, not just the post it's linked to.

Site A can link to Site B as many times as it likes, and each post may link to more than one other post. An example scenario might be:

- Site A links to Site B
- Site C links to Site B
- Site D links to Site A

In the above data:

- Site A could link to Site C (or Site B again)
- Site B could link to Site D
- Site C could link to Site A or Site D (or Site B again)
- Site D could link to Site B or Site C (or Site A again)

Here is a link to some test data and a dump of the 2 tables needed:
http://pastie.org/1506715

I think I need a cross join to get all possible linking combinations, but then factor in existing relationships to prevent sites from linking back in the opposite direction. The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
t1.* , t2.* FROM test_posts t1, test_posts as t2
WHERE
t1.post_id != t2.post_id
ORDER BY
t1.post_id, t2.post_id;
```

This gives me all possible relationships between posts. What I'm struggling with is how to exclude relationships that would contradict the above rules. The previous relationships are recorded in the test_smartlinks_to_websites table, with post_id belonging the "originating" website and website_id belonging to the "destination" site (remembering that the relationship is effectively one-way between websites, not posts).

I have tried using a NOT EXISTS subquery, but I'm unsure on the exact clause (or whether that is the correct approach).

Comment: So this is a completely hierarchical level of posts??? ie: A links to B, B can link to C, C to D, so even though C and D are not explicitly linked to A, can A have a direct link to C and/or D even though they are under B?  Additionally, in THIS sample B would also not allow a link to D or can it since its not DIRECTLY linked?

Comment: It's not a hierarchy, it's sort of like a web of links, but none of the sites should like back, everything should be one-way. (I'm working with BrynJ on this)

Comment: There's a lot about blogs, posts in the question...but there's a disconnect between that and your tables...what table stores what...where is the blog data..where is post data...??
where are the links that u have talked so much about stored in the table...?

Comment: Tip: If you are trying to solve a technical difficulty...try leaving the domain details out...It will reduce the size of your question and it will also really help others in providing a quick answer...

Comment: @Mulki The post_id refers to the blog post, and the website_id to the blog site. More or less fields other than these can be ignored - test_smartlink_to_websites is the key table, where previous post to website relationships are recorded.

Comment: @BrynJ Can you post your not exists/except query...I think its a good way to go about it...

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if I am wrong. It appears your task is to determine cycles in directed graph. It's not that complex as it seems. Please see this blog post for how it's done in SQL: http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/finding-cycles-in-directed-graphs-using-tsql/. Also see this link for the breadth first search in SQL: http://willets.org/sqlgraphs.html.

EDITED: added images for clarity and understanding of directed acyclic and cyclic graphs.

For example, here is something that resembles your situation. It's not a single graph but a set of graphs (or forest if they were trees). Note there is no common root. It's just nodes connected somehow. There is a cycle in the bigger subgraph where to nodes reference each other. If to remove the link upwards, the subgraph becomes acyclic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've read the content and, if I'm honest, I don't understand some the intricacies - however I think the problems described there are a little more complex. I simply need to establish from a recorded set of relationships, that if site A links to B, B can't link to A ...and return all potential valid permutations of the site linking.

Comment: That was my first impression...but the examples in the post shows otherwise...notice 
"Site B could link to Site D" in the example...since d is linked to A and A to B that makes it circular...but allowed...It looks like he's just searching for a trackback..anything with a backward reference

Comment: @BrynJ: uhm... that's what directed graph is. A,C->B->D and a cycle A,C->B->D->C,F. Try to draw that and it will be clearer.

Comment: I have added an image for clarity.